# Extract passwords from settings.py file

Tags: python, django, settings

I would like to extract any sensitive information from my settings.py file, for example, db name/password, amazon key/password, api keys/passwords. What is the suggested way to go about doing this.

Comment: Where else would you put them?

Comment: In a separate file, if this is possible.

Comment: This is useful when you want `settings.py` in version control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move all the keys, passwords, etc. to a file `secrets.py`, then add `import secrets` to `settings.py`.